# How can I get a parent route params from a child component using activatedRoute?

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-activatedroute

I am working with a child component and I am having trouble getting access (I think) to it's parent route params.

My url looks like this:

```
/settings/organizations/26ee00d1-9fd8-4e38-a195-024c11ae0958/locations/914adefe-6b08-4f7a-9e3e-fa671a52fd3c/resources
```

Here is what my route(s) look like:

```
// routes.ts

path: 'settings/organizations/:organizationId/locations/:locationId',
component: LocationSettingsSummaryComponent,
children: [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LocationSettingsComponent,
    },
    {
       path: 'resources',
       component: ResourcesSummaryComponent,
    },
]
```

Here is what my child component looks like:

```
// resources-summary.commponent.ts

...

organizationId!: string;
locationId!: string;

constructor(
    ...
    private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) {}


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.organizationId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('organizationId');
    this.locationId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('locationId')';

    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params); // {}
}
```

In other components, I have been able to get to an `organiationId` via:

```
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('organizationId')
```

For example, getting location details, I'm able to use this url and get the apropreate parameters

```
/settings/organizations/26ee00d1-9fd8-4e38-a195-024c11ae0958/locations/914adefe-6b08-4f7a-9e3e-fa671a52fd3c


this.locationId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('locationId')'; // 914adefe-6b08-4f7a-9e3e-fa671a52fd3c
```

I have tried various methods of getting the parent:

```
console.log(this.activatedRoute.parent?.params); // {}
```

But that too seems to always be empty, or an empty object.

I found it interesting that from my component if I do this:

```
console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot); // resources
```

It seems like Angular is having trouble finding the parent?

In this component, the `activatedRoute` params seem to always be empty. How can I get access to the route params from this child component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `paramMap` from the parent of the `ActivatedRoute` like the following:

```js
const parentParamMap = this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.paramMap;
const organizationId = parentParamMap.get('organizationId');
```

Comment: Arg! I was trying to get to the `parent` without setting a variable to get the data from. Thank you so much!

Comment: Perfect solution saved so much time! Thanks